# Querying same document in parallel in the same API in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, promise, parallel-processing

I have a an API written in typescript and I try to run parallel queries for same document by using promise.allsettled however it performs worse and I guess they run sequentially. Is there a way to perform parallel queries on the same document in the same connection for mongoDB. here is the code:

```
console.time("normal");
let normal = await ContentRepo.geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered(
    [chosenSkillsArr[0].sid!],
    readContentIds,
    body.isVideoIncluded,
    true,
    true
);
console.timeEnd("normal");

console.time("parallel");
const parallel = await Promise.allSettled(
    chosenSkillsArr.map(async (skill: IScrapeSkillDocument) => {
        const result = await ContentRepo.geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered(
            [skill.sid!],
            readContentIds,
            body.isVideoIncluded,
            true,
            true
        );
    })
);
console.timeEnd("parallel");
```

The function I called is here:

```
async geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered(
    skillIds: string[],
    contentIds: string[],
    isVideoIncluded?: boolean,
    isCuratorIdFilter?: boolean,
    activeSourceFilter?: boolean
): Promise<IContentWithSource[]> {
    try {
        console.time(`single-${skillIds}`);
        var contents = await ContentM.find({
            $and: [
                { "skills.skillId": { $in: skillIds } },
                { recordStatus: true },
                isCuratorIdFilter ? { curatorId: 0 } : {},
                isVideoIncluded ? {} : { type: contentTypeNumber.read },
                { _id: { $nin: contentIds } },
            ],
        }).exec();
        var items: IContentWithSource[] = [];
        var sourceIds = new Set<string>();
        contents.forEach((content) => {
            if (!this.isEmpty(content.sourceId)) {
                sourceIds.add(content.sourceId!);
            }
        });
        var sources: any = {};
        var sourcesArr = await new SourceRepo().getByIds(
            Array.from(sourceIds)
        );
        sourcesArr.forEach((source) => {
            sources[source._id] = source;
        });

        if (activeSourceFilter) {
            contents
                .map((i) => i.toJSON() as IContentWithSource)
                .map((k) => {
                    if (sources[k.sourceId!].isActive) {
                        k.source = sources[k.sourceId!];
                        items.push(k);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            contents
                .map((i) => i.toJSON() as IContentWithSource)
                .map((k) => {
                    k.source = sources[k.sourceId!];
                    items.push(k);
                });
        }
        console.timeEnd(`single-${skillIds}`);

        return items;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
single-KS120B874P2P6BK1MQ0T: 1872.735ms
normal: 1873.934ms
single-KS120B874P2P6BK1MQ0T: 3369.925ms
single-KS440QS66YCBN23Y8K25: 3721.214ms
single-KS1226Y6DNDT05G7FJ4J: 3799.050ms
parallel: 3800.586ms
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running more code in the parallel version

```js
// The normal version
let normal = await ContentRepo.geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered(
    [chosenSkillsArr[0].sid!],
    readContentIds,
    body.isVideoIncluded,
    true,
    true
);


// The code inside the parallel version:
chosenSkillsArr.map(async (skill: IScrapeSkillDocument) => {
        const result = await ContentRepo.geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered(
            [skill.sid!],
            readContentIds,
            body.isVideoIncluded,
            true,
            true
        );
    })
```

```
[chosenSkillsArr[0].sid!], vs  chosenSkillsArr.map()
```

For the parallel version, you are putting the function call (`ContentRepo.geBySkillIdWithSourceFiltered`) inside a loop. That's why it is slower.

### For the question about running promises in parallel:

Like `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled` await multiple promises. It doesn't care about what order they resolve, or whether the computations are running in parallel. They both do not guarantee concurrency nor the opposite. Their task is just to ensure all the promises passed to it are handled.

So you can't manually guarantee the parallelism of promise execution

Here is a really [interesting article](https://anotherdev.xyz/promise-all-runs-in-parallel/) explaining parallelism and `Promise.All` and how browser Nodejs API differs from Nodejs API installed on your computer in terms of parallelism.

Here is the extract of the article's conclusion:

> JavaScript runtime is single-threaded. We do not have access to thread in JavaScript. Even if you have multi-core CPU you still can't run tasks in parallel using JavaScript. But, the browser/NodeJS uses C/C++ (!) where they have access to thread. So, they can achieve parallelism.

### Side Note:

There is one subtle difference:

1. Promise.all: Resolves only when all promises passed to it resolves else it will reject with the first rejected promise error.
2. Promise.allSettled: Will always get resolved with an array having info about resolved and rejected promises.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation. I tried promise.allSettled without using a map but putting requests by hand. But it did not change anything. I guess it can be a problem related to mongoDb .do you have any idea about running queries in mongoDB for parallel.

Comment: I think it is not a problem with MongoDB but the autonomy of Nodejs and its single-threadedness. Let say there are 10 people running toward a counter to get a movie ticket. All of them start at exactly the same place and exactly the time. Someone will arrive first and the clerk at the counter will serve whoever is the first to arrive. Consider the counter as the CPU and those 10 people are 10 different promises. No matter who starts first or how close is someone to the counter, the counter can only serve one person at a time. That's the case for Nodejs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, then I should search another ways to increase query performance.

Comment: I am glad that I answered your question. At least part of it. Just a side note, avoid putting database calls in loops if possible.